# Formik + Yup don't validate input if untouched

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to use Formik + Yup to validate my form, but currently if I touch one field, and then try and submit, a field that has a minimum length will validate, and not allow me to submit.

Following my code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-bardeen-5fiuz), I want the user to be able to submit the form if they just change the `firstName` field, but without entering anything for the `country` field. I tried both the `.notRequired()` and `.nullable(true)` params, but did not work. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use custom validate with `test`. A working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dust-f9wet

```
country: yup
      .string()
      .test("isValidCode", "Country must be 2-letters (ISO codes).", value => {
        if (!value) {
          return true;
        }
        return value.toString().length === 2;
      })
```